# CodeLLDB and VSCode - How to print an array

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, debugging, lldb

Using the CodeLLDB extension, I'm successfully debugging my C projects with lldb in VSCode.

The problem is that I cannot use lldb commands in the VSCode watch window.
For example, I'm trying to print the first 10 items in an array using `parray <COUNT> <EXPRESSION>`.
This is what I obtain:

[image]

Is there a way to manipulate data using lldb?

For reference, with GDB you can do `*myarr@10` in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

`parray` is an lldb command line command.  It looks like the watch window expects an expression, not lldb commands.  lldb's expression parser, unlike gdb's, is just the underlying language parser (e.g. it uses a copy of clang for C++).  That makes it a more faithful evaluator of the expressions you hand it, but limits what debugger centric syntax we can introduce (like the gdb `@10`).  So you could `watch` the elements one by one, but there isn't C syntax for "elements 0-9 of an array" so the expression parser doesn't support that either.

Presumably, VSCode has a "debugger console" for debugger commands.  That's where you would enter the parray command.  lldb also has `stop hooks`, so if you wanted to see this array's values in the console each time you stopped, you could do:

```
(lldb) target stop-hook add -o "parray 10 passport.data"
```

stop hooks can be set to trigger only for certain functions, so you could limit this printing to the function where passport is defined, as well.